Including Current Date in Header of Exported DataTable in Laravel DataTables
I am using Laravel with the Laravel DataTables package. I have added the export button to the DataTable, but I need to include the current date at the top of the page
var dtconfig = {
            dom:
                "<'row'<'col-md-12 text-center'B>>" + // Fila superior: botones centrados
                "<'row'<'col-md-6'l><'col-md-6'f>>" + // Fila inferior: selector de cantidad a la izquierda, búsqueda a la derecha
                "<'row'<'col-md-12't>>" + // Fila para la tabla
                "<'row'<'col-md-6'i><'col-md-6'p>>", //
            buttons: [
                'excel', ['pdf'], 'print',
            ],
            buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'excel',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':not(.not-exportable)' // Exportar todas las columnas excepto las marcadas como no exportables
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdf',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':not(.not-exportable)' // Exportar todas las columnas excepto las marcadas como no exportables
                },
                customize: function(doc) {
                    doc.content[0].text = doc.content[0].text  + '<div style="float:right">'+ moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY') +'</div>'

                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'print',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':not(.not-exportable)' // Exportar todas las columnas excepto las marcadas como no exportables
                }
            }
        ]
    };

The problem is that the HTML code is not interpreted; it appears as a literal string in the exported document rather than being interpreted as HTML.
My Questions:
How can I correctly include HTML in the exported PDF such that it renders properly and ensures that the style declaration takes effect?
What are the properties of the obj parameter in the customize method for the PDF export option, and how can I utilize them effectively?
